# Designing a drag and drop web image configurator for a web store without flash

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, web

I don't even know what to call this., but I'm trying to figure out how to do "configurator" type thing for a web store - something similar to this: www.flowerbox.de/content/FlowerBox-Konfigurator.html

Imagine having a picture of a man on the left and you can drag and drop different clothes (pants, shirts etc...) on him. I.e. pants snap on his legs etc... Click around a little on the site I posted to see how that works.

Now the question I have could this be done without flash and where could I read more on this to point me in the right direction. Any articles, tutorials, code snippets would be nice.

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I'm still trying to figure out if this can be done without the use of flash. First impressions seem to be that it would just be easier to make in flash, but I'm still doing research.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery UI Draggable/Droppable methods. It's certainly possible without flash:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Specifically look at the Snap Elements to Grid sample.